# javascript code isn't working. May be attaching it to the html page incorrectly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

So I am trying to create a timer but my javascript isn't working.  Am I attaching it to the page wrong?  I'm kinda new to js so I'm not quite sure what the problem is.  If anyone could point out what exactly I'm doing wrong and how to fix it I would really appreciate it!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE html
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
 <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nixie+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {
    var rounds  = 3;
    var states  = ['work', 'rest', 'wait'];
    var lengths = [3, 1, 2]; // In seconds
    var start   = $('#start');
    var stop    = $('#stop');
    var stats   = $('#stats');
    var roundEl = $('#round');
    var stateEl = $('#state');
    var cronoEl = $('#crono');
    var timer;

    start.click(function () {
        var ctimer, date;

        // UI
        start.prop('disabled', true);
        stop.prop('disabled', false);
        stats.show();

        // Start round
        nextRound(0);

        function nextRound(round) {
            // Update UI
            roundEl.html(round + 1);

            if (round < rounds) {
                // Start new round                
                nextState(round, 0);                
            } else {
                // We have finished
                stop.click();
            }
        }

        function nextState(round, state) {
            if (state < states.length) {                
                stateEl.html(states[state]);

                // Start crono UI
                time   = new Date();
                ctimer = setInterval(crono, 15);

                // State timer
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    clearInterval(ctimer);
                    nextState(round, state + 1);
                }, lengths[state] * 1000);
            } else {
                nextRound(round + 1);
            }
        }

        function crono() {
            cronoEl.html((((new Date()).getTime() - time.getTime()) / 1000).toFixed(2));
        }
    });

    stop.click(function () {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        start.prop('disabled', false);
        stop.prop('disabled', true);
        stats.hide();
    });
});

    </script>   
    <title>Workitt</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <input id="start" value="START" type="button" />
    <input id="stop" value="STOP" type="button" disabled />
    <div id="stats" class="stats" style="display:none;">
        Round: <span id="round"></span><br>
        State: <span id="state" class="state"></span><br>
        Time: <span id="crono"></span>s<br>
    </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mWQ8g/ what is not working ? check the link and tell me

Comment: This is working for me too: http://jqversion.com/#!/p8SjEfL

Comment: Psst. Don’t write XHTML. Especially if you’re not going to write valid XHTML. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is really simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using jquery 1.4 and `prop()` is added in 1.6.

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
```

and it will run.

Comment: I would recommend 1.* latest version compared to 2.* versions for more IE support i.e 2.* version is not supported in Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Answer (score 1):

Change the jquery path to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

to make sure you always have the latest jquery code.

Answer (score 0):

With the DOCTYPE that you have you have to change your script tag to this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Also, `.prop()` is not available in that version of jQuery - use `.attr()` instead.

Comment: Technically, yes. But that's not going to cause his problem.

Comment: *Also, `.prop()` is not available in that version of jQuery - use `.attr()` instead.* No, use an up-to-date version of jQuery instead.

Comment: What if the OP doesn't have that option @minitech?

Comment: *“So I am trying to create a timer”* OP has that option. It’s available from the same CDN. If they’re trying to fix the problem without changing the markup or the JavaScript, well, that *is* a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use an older version of jQuery

As you can see in the following test: http://jqversion.com/#!/p8SjEfL/1 in version 2.0.1 it works but in 1.4.x is not working..